# Numerous remote errors when following TensorFlow Pets on Google Cloud tutorial

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform

Following instructions in the "Distributed Training on the Oxford-IIIT Pets Dataset on Google Cloud" tutorial [on the official TensorFlow Models repo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/running_pets.md), I'm running into some issues. First, this:

> Termination reason: Error. Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
>   "**main**", fname, loader, pkg_name) File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code exec code in
>   run_globals File
>   "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/train.py",
>   line 51, in  from object_detection.builders import
>   model_builder File
>   "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/builders/model_builder.py",
>   line 29, in  from object_detection.meta_architectures import
>   ssd_meta_arch File
>   "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/meta_architectures/ssd_meta_arch.py",
>   line 32, in  from object_detection.utils import
>   visualization_utils File
>   "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/utils/visualization_utils.py",
>   line 25, in  import matplotlib; matplotlib.use('Agg') #
>   pylint: disable=multiple-statements ImportError: No module named
>   matplotlib

The takeaway from this was the last part - "No module named matplotlib". Following some advice online, I edited the provided setup.py, to add "matplotlib" as a requirement:

```
REQUIRED_PACKAGES = ['Pillow>=1.0', 'matplotlib']
```

Running it again, that solved the issue. Odd - you'd assume with it being a tutorial, it wouldn't have that issue. Next though, it ran into a new issue:

> Termination reason: Error. Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
>   "**main**", fname, loader, pkg_name) File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code exec code in
>   run_globals File
>   "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/train.py",
>   line 167, in  tf.app.run() File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py",
>   line 48, in run _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
>   File
>   "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/train.py",
>   line 163, in main worker_job_name, is_chief, FLAGS.train_dir) File
>   "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/trainer.py",
>   line 264, in train train_config.prefetch_queue_capacity,
>   data_augmentation_options) File
>   "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/trainer.py",
>   line 59, in create_input_queue tensor_dict = create_tensor_dict_fn()
>   File
>   "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/train.py",
>   line 120, in get_next dataset_builder.build(config)).get_next() File
>   "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/builders/dataset_builder.py",
>   line 164, in build functools.partial(tf.data.TFRecordDataset,
>   buffer_size=8 * 1000 * 1000), AttributeError: 'module' object has no
>   attribute 'data' The replica worker 0 exited with a non-zero status of
>   1.

With no relevant search results for this issue, it's difficult to know what the problem is, though one answer suggested an out of date version of TensorFlow. The stated TensorFlow version for this project is TensorFlow 1.2. TensorFlow is now on version 1.7, so maybe that's where the issue arrises. The options for runtime version list are 1.2, 1.4, 1.5 and 1.6. Trying it with 1.6, I got a different error:

> Termination reason: Error. Traceback (most recent call last): [...]
>   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/slim/python/slim/learning.py",
>   line 746, in train master, start_standard_services=False,
>   config=session_config) as sess: File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 17, in **enter** return
>   self.gen.next() File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py",
>   line 1000, in managed_session
>   self.stop(close_summary_writer=close_summary_writer) File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py",
>   line 828, in stop ignore_live_threads=ignore_live_threads) File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/coordinator.py",
>   line 389, in join six.reraise(*self._exc_info_to_raise) File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py",
>   line 989, in managed_session
>   start_standard_services=start_standard_services) File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py",
>   line 734, in prepare_or_wait_for_session max_wait_secs=max_wait_secs)
>   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/session_manager.py",
>   line 402, in wait_for_session sess) File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/session_manager.py",
>   line 486, in _try_run_local_init_op sess.run(self._local_init_op) File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py",
>   line 905, in run run_metadata_ptr) File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py",
>   line 1137, in _run feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata) File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py",
>   line 1355, in _do_run options, run_metadata) File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py",
>   line 1374, in _do_call raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
>   UnavailableError: OS Error The replica worker 1 exited with a non-zero
>   status of 1.

Again, there doesn't seem to be a solution to this error right now. So I'm stabbing in the dark. I try it again with TensorFlow 1.4. New error:

> Termination reason: Error. Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
>   "**main**", fname, loader, pkg_name) File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code exec code in
>   run_globals File
>   "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/train.py",
>   line 167, in  tf.app.run() File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py",
>   line 48, in run _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
>   File
>   "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/train.py",
>   line 163, in main worker_job_name, is_chief, FLAGS.train_dir) File
>   "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/trainer.py",
>   line 264, in train train_config.prefetch_queue_capacity,
>   data_augmentation_options) File
>   "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/trainer.py",
>   line 59, in create_input_queue tensor_dict = create_tensor_dict_fn()
>   File
>   "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/train.py",
>   line 120, in get_next dataset_builder.build(config)).get_next() File
>   "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/builders/dataset_builder.py",
>   line 165, in build process_fn, config.input_path[:],
>   input_reader_config) File
>   "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/utils/dataset_util.py",
>   line 133, in read_dataset tf.contrib.data.parallel_interleave(
>   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'parallel_interleave'
>   The replica worker 0 exited with a non-zero status of 1

I'm finding myself deep within a world of errors now, and don't really know what my next steps should be. I'm simply following the steps of the tutorial, executing the lines of code they say to execute, and receiving these remote errors after 5-10 mins of execution.

Any advice on how to overcome these issues would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried finding a better tutorial? One that works perhaps

Comment: @musefan this is an official tutorial - other tutorials which cover the same area always reference these tutorials for those specific steps

Answer (score 0):

You have an installation issue. Uninstall everything and confirm uninstalled by starting Python and importing what you uninstalled to ensure you observe ImportError for each uninstalled package.

Then carefully follow the steps on [the installation page](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md) which indeed indicate separate installation steps for matplotlib and more.

Comment: matplotlib and other libraries are installed locally. The script at the end of the installation instructions runs without issue, as do other scripts. The problem is that on the Google Cloud instance, I'm running into issues.

Comment: A "google cloud instance" is a vm, you're saying your script works locally but not in the vm? And you've done per the above answer in the vm too?

Answer (score 0):

Some of these errors were supposed to be happening until [the following commit](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/pull/4087/files).
Using the [repo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models) now, following the instructions in [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/running_pets.md) works for me. Only looks like you need to use `--runtime-version 1.7` flag. 
If you keep having issues make sure you are following the [installation instructions](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md) using `sudo`.

If not, some people were still saying they needed to add Tensorflow and Jupyter also in the [setup.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/4058) (that was not my case though)